# UISearchDisplayController does not showing when adding programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have created a UISearchDisplayController now while adding programatically it is not showing.

[self presentModalViewController:self.searchDisplayController animated:YES];

So i checked the Apple Guide and findout this class is not inherited from UIViewController but from NSObject!

So Is there any solution available to achieve this?

Any body has done this before?

Comment: Can you post the code you used to create the `UISearchDisplayController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UISearchDisplayController` can't be hidden or shown - it's just the manager for an `UISearchBar`. `UISearchBar` inherits from `UIView`, which is what you want to work with.

Comment: so if i need to present modally UISearchDisplayController is there any way?

Comment: Again: you can't display a `controller` - only a `view`. So the view - in your case a `UISearchBar` would be the object you want to pass to you modal view controller.

Comment: So you want to say UISearchDisplayController is not inherited from UIViewController, i can not able to show searchdisplaycontroller modally.Like i usually do with viewcontroller.

Comment: Correct. `presentModalViewController` wants a `UIViewController`. `UISearchDisplayController` is something different. That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

As @SAE said, `UISearchDisplayController` only manages a `UISearchBar`.
You must create a separate view controller, add a search bar as a subview and present it.